# Postgres RLS Policy to show items based on its permissions listed on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, authorization, supabase

I have in my database tables for posts and users (with user-id as primary key and it's role on second column). I'm trying to create a new policy which allow users with admin role to read, edit and delete all posts. I have the variable auth.uid() available that should be looked up in the users table, and then get whether it's permission equals admin.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. Any magic solution?

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Admins have full control over all items" ON "Posts"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR ALL
TO public
USING (auth.uid() in ( select user_id from Users where permission = "admin" ))
```

Comment: `select user_id from Users where permission = "admin"` is going to be an expensive query.  I think that a better approach would be to create a group with privileges and checking there.  

At the bottom of [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) you should be able to take an example by searching for `-- definition of privilege groups`.

Comment: Do you see any errors? How do you test it?

Comment: @Mansueli why? It's gonna be a pretty fast with an index. `select count(user_id) > 0 from Users where permission = "admin" and user_id = auth.uid()` is gonna be a bit faster though

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you use Supabase:

1. Create a new function:

```
create or replace function get_admin_users()
returns setof uuid
language sql
security definer
set search_path = public
stable
as $$
    select user_id 
    from Users 
    where Users.permission = 'admin'
$$;
```

2. Create a new policy:

```
    create policy "For admin"
      on Posts
      for all using (
        auth.uid() in (
          select get_admin_users()
        )
      );
```

Please let me know how you test it or which errors you receive etc.

Thank you!